# Run Ember-Table in Flask template

Tags: javascript, python, ember.js, flask, jinja2

I'm making a app with Flask and [Ember-Table](https://addepar.github.io/#/ember-table/overview). Jinja2 run on the server side and Handlebars will run on the client side.  I use `{% extends "layout.html" %}` and `{% block content %}` from Jinja2 and simple [example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/feqih/1/edit) of Ember-Table in the same template (home.html). When I run with the code above:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

I have this error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'hasFooter'
```

What I understand is, Jinja2 want to interpret Ember and this is the error. Who I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`{% raw %}`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#escaping) to have Jinja ignore part of your template:

```
{% raw %}
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2> Welcome to Ember Table!</h2>
    <p>Version 0.2.0</p>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div class="table-container">
      {{table-component
        hasFooter=false
        columnsBinding="columns"
        contentBinding="content"
      }}
    </div>
  </script>
</body>
{% endraw %}
```